# What exactly Membership Service Provider (MSP) is in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

While reading the documentation on Hyperledger Fabric I couldn't understand what MSP is. It is really unclear to me what an MSP exactly is and how it differs from CA?

What I understand is CA issue certificates and MSP says which of these are valid and belong to a certain organization. But, what exactly it is?

Is the MSP some kind of a server that has some kind of an interface, that other peers and orderers use, or is it a bunch of directories that contain configuration, or what exactly it is? How can I view it?

The documentation describes what its role is and how it fits into the blockchain network. But not what exactly what it is.

When I run a simple dev fabric network, decker contains a process for peer, orderer, and a CA. Where is the MSP?

I've checked these questions but none of them explains what MSP actually is.

- [Hyperledger Fabric docs on Membership Service Provider - Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52357596/hyperledger-fabric-docs-on-membership-service-provider-questions)
- [Hyperledger fabric understanding MSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53297909/hyperledger-fabric-understanding-msp)
- [What is the difference between MSP and Fabric CA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45682958/what-is-the-difference-between-msp-and-fabric-ca)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

OK, so I was able, hopefully, to answer my question. I will answer it in the form of points.

- The name "MSP" is, in my opinion, a poorly chosen name. The word "service" implies having a working process/program/server in place, like Web Service, Rest Service etc. The word "Provider" also implies that it provides the membership service and finally I imagine that this is some kind of an OAuth or LDAP Server or something alike, it is not. ***It a bunch of directories with digital certificates.*** Probably a better name would be Members Certificates Directory (MCD) or Members Certificates Registry (MCR).
- After realizing that these are directories from the documentation

> To **set up a local MSP** (for either a peer or an orderer), the
> administrator should **create a folder** (e.g. $MY_PATH/mspconfig) that
> contains six subfolders and a file

*Also set up implies starting and configure a process/server or something alike.*

- So I entered the peer container of the [Dev Servers](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org.html) created for Hyperledger Composer development and searched for a $FABRIC_CFG_PATH

[image]

- the ***/msp*** **DIRECTORY** is the MSP directory and it contains directories explained in the [docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/msp.html#msp-setup-on-the-peer-orderer-side)
  And it is configured as required by the documents:

> The path to the mspconfig folder is expected to be relative to
> FABRIC_CFG_PATH and is provided as the value of parameter
> mspConfigPath for the peer, and LocalMSPDir for the orderer

[image]

[image]

I hope this clears uncertainty for others as it did for me and the docs of fabric updated for more clarity.

Comment: I had exactly same question, and come to the same conclusion you mention.
Msp is just a directory.

Comment: @engineerk A poorly chosen name results in scratching your head for hours to understand what it is.

Comment: Don't confuse its function with its implementation.  Yes, it is JUST a set of directories containing certs, but that is just an implementation detail.  The implementation could be replaced as well as extended as basically the MSP only allows you to define who is an admin vs who is just a normally authenticated user.  The value of the current implementation is that each participant is able to decide what they consider someone else, i.e., admin or user.  Pretty coarse grained, but it works.

Comment: It's not only a bunch of directories, it's consist of a suite of APIs and interface to deal with them.

Answer (score 4):

Hyperledger fabric 2.2. documentation explains it as per the accepted answer.

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/membership/membership.html

**What is MSP**

Despite its name, the **Membership Service Provider does not actually provide anything**. Rather, **the implementation of the MSP requirement is a set of folders that are added to the configuration of the network**... Whereas Certificate Authorities generate the certificates that represent identities, **the MSP contains a list of permissioned identities**.

Two types of MSP :

**Local MSPs** are represented as a folder structure on the file system

**Channel MSPs** are described in a channel configuration.

Comment: So finally they have fixed it ! Nice !

Answer (score 1):

The confusion may come from the fact HLF is both defining the [MSP as an abstraction layer](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/msp.html) and providing a simplistic implementation (using directories).

MSP documentation -link above- clearly states `In the rest of this document we elaborate on the setup of the MSP **implementation** supported by Hyperledger Fabric`